# How to wrap a List of Widgets without changing the layout when unwrapped and spread in a Row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

Currently, the following structure gives me the intended layout:

```
Consumer<State>(
  builder(context, state, child) => Row(
    children: [
      Widget1(...), // fixed width
      ...List.generate(state.length, (index) => Expanded(child: Widget2(index, state))),
    ]
  )
)
```

Widget1 does not need to be hooked up to state, and so I don't want it to be rerendered when it changes. It would be great if `List.generate` could be hooked to a `Consumer`, but `builder` needs to return a single Widget, not a list of Widgets.

I've tried using the `Wrap` widget around the list, and hooking that to a `Consumer`. This accomplishes my goal of not rerendering Widget1, but it changes the layout - the Widget2's don't expand to fill the remaining space any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Widget1(...), // fixed width
      Consumer<State>(
       builder: (context, state, child) {
          return Expanded(
                   child: Row(
                     children: List.generate(
                       state.length,
                       (index) {
                         return Expanded(
                           child: Widget2(index, state),
                         );
                       },
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
               },
             ),
           ],
         ),
```